# Parsing an Comparing FullNames on a Join between two tables

Tags: sql

I want to compare two strings from two different tables which contain the full name of a person is this format "Blow, Joe" since in one table the user may have the full name like that and other table might have the same user but the full name as "Blow, Joseph) so I want to grab the first two character from both the first and last name and see if they match. Then if they do I wan to update the record. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I was getting an out of range error and now I am getting incorrect syntax near 'SUBSTRING' which I am looking into now. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeMaster e
JOIN EmployeeDivisions d ON SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(e.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName) - 1))),' ',''),1,3) LIKE SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(d.Name,CHARINDEX(',',d.Name) - 1))),' ',''),1,3)
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(e.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName) + 1, LEN(e.FullName)))),' ',''),1,3) LIKE SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(d.Name,CHARINDEX(',',d.Name) + 1, LEN(d.Name)))),' ',''),1,3)
```

Comment: I'd use a CTE to split it up, then do the join.  It'll make it a bit more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I don't have to point out that this check might match names that are very different. In your example `Blow, Joseph`would match not only`Blow, Joe`but also`Black, John`and so on...

Maybe you should at least extend the check to include the complete surname together with part of the given name.

But... if you still want to compare the first two letters in the word before the comma, and the first two letters in the word after the comma then use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeMaster e
JOIN EmployeeDivisions d ON 
(
 SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(e.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName) - 1))),' ',''),1,2) 
 =
 SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(d.Name,CHARINDEX(',',d.Name) - 1))),' ',''),1,2)
)
AND 
(
 SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(e.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName) + 1, LEN(e.FullName)))),' ',''),1,2) 
 = 
 SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(d.Name,CHARINDEX(',',d.Name) + 1, LEN(d.Name)))),' ',''),1,2)
)
```

You might be able to reduce the complexity of the join to this:

```
LEFT(LTRIM(e.FullName),CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName)-1) 
= 
LEFT(LTRIM(d.Name),CHARINDEX(',',d.Name)-1)
AND 
SUBSTRING(e.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',e.FullName) + 1, 3) 
= 
SUBSTRING(d.Name,CHARINDEX(',',d.Name) + 1, 3)
```

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about that as well. There isn't too many names left. But enough to have a terrible time doing manual entries haha but i will add that in there as well. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I am still getting an invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function

Comment: @user3788671 That will happen if one of the columns is too short so that the third parameter to substring will have a negative value; it's a bit hard to tell where it happens though.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I tried adding this e.FullName IS NOT NULL AND d.Name IS NOT NULL AND LEN(e.FullName) > 0 AND LEN(d.Name) > 0

Comment: @user3788671 If there is any rows the has a fullname or name without the comma it will fail too; that is something you want to check.

Comment: That still did not work. When I comment out the first part of the join. It runs. Does the first set of LEFT's need a length?

Comment: @user3788671 Are you using the original version in the query or the simplified version I added at the bottom?

Comment: So the issue was that there were some columns that did not contain commas. So it would return -1. I fixed this by adding commas